# Is it possible to add custom comment tokens to visual studio programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio

TODO:, HACK:, etc. don't quite cut it for me. Is there a way to programmatically add tokens (i.e. from a build task)?

This shows you how to add them manually: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekwz6akh(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, the "note" [in this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awdwz11a(v=vs.80).aspx) makes me think so: *"Some items on some Options pages are not programmatically accessible. Most items, such as the comment Token list in the Task List Options page, can be viewed or changed programmatically. But some Options pages, such as the Dynamic Help page, which is in the Help node of the Environment page, cannot."* Not sure how, though. I spend enough time programming *in* Visual Studio without being bothered to program *to* Visual Studio! :-)