# How to programmatically create custom comment tokens

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a small Visual Studio addin to let the user use more features of the comment tokens (TODO, HACK, etc.). For this I want to extend Visual Studio with new commands (such as TODISCUSS, TODELETE, FIXME, TESTME, etc.). I'd like to do this programmatically when my addin starts.

I already found out how to do this manually: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekwz6akh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done via the API?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: In case you are not aware, [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) already has functionality to do this, as well as much, much more useful stuff besides.

Comment: Did you see the "Community Addition" added in 2010 at the link you mentioned? AFAIUY that answers your question, unless there is an indirect API that then updates the registry for you.

Comment: Also [this would be a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671440/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-comment-tokens-to-visual-studio-programmatically?rq=1) except you've been specific to 2012.

Comment: @nateirvin Yes, I am but I want to go beyond Resharper's functionality in my small university project.

Comment: @Mark Hurd: Yes, thanks. But I couldn't find it in the registry ...
& 
Unfortunately, this is in Visual Basic don't know - nevertheless, thanks for pointing out this thread. I'll try to figure it out in C# ...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :**

See this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.tasklist.defaultcommenttoken%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) perhaps digging around in TaskList will get you somewhere.

**Original Post :**

It's not very clear (to me :) what exactly you want to do. Is it: find, edit, or refactor the tokens and then do something else with the sources? I can suggest this article on Code Project ([NRefactory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408663/Using-NRefactory-for-analyzing-Csharp-code)).

Using NRefactory you can do anything and everything with the source files including locating the tokens you want and doing stuff with them. You will also know the files you found them in, line numbers etc.

Perhaps you will be able to use Nrefactory to do all the heavy lifting as far as sources are concerned.

Comment: hi Alex. Thanks for your answer. I don't want to refactor anything. I want to extend the possible comment tokens available in Visual Studio. Currently, there are only TODO, FIXME and BUG available. I want to add for example HACK, TOCREATE, etc. programmatically (and not manually via the settings). Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hey C. I'm afraid I can't help you there. See my last edit...I hope it helps.